# Removing Meta Generator

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I've noticed in the source of my page is shows in the meta generator `Wow-Themes.com`. I have been trying to remove this from the source using

```
    function rm_generator_filter() { return ''; }

if (function_exists('add_filter')) {
  $types = array('html', 'xhtml', 'atom', 'rss2',
                 /*'rdf',*/ 'comment', 'export');
  foreach ($types as $type)
    add_filter('get_the_generator_'.$type, 'rm_generator_filter');
}
```

None of which has worked. I've also tried Googling for ages and put similar codes into the `functions.php` file however this also does nothing.

I've also downloaded and installed `head cleaner` from the WordPress plugin repository, and checked the `remove meta generator` box and this also has not worked.

Does anyone have any other suggestions please?

Comment: search your theme it may be adding it's own filter?

Comment: I have tried searching the theme files can't seem to find nothing...

Comment: Did you search for action `wp_head` ?

Comment: Yes haven't found nothing.I've even just remove the 
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_generator'                           );
From the default-filters.php in wp includes but its still shows the generator line in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to remove this. If anyone else is wondering how simply go to.

/themes/theme-name/includes/helpers

open up SEO.php. And do Ctrl+F for generator or Wow-Themes.